# How to print in text view line by line using loop?

Tags: android, string, loops, textview

```
for (Element eHead : eHeadder) 
 {
String tag = eHead.tagName();
    if(tag.equals("p")
    {
     final String parsedText = eHead.text();
     Log.d("testing5", parsedText);
     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
       {
         public void run() { 
         data.setText(parsedText);
                            }    
        });
      }
  }
```

In the above code, I get line of datas from "p"(paragraph) tag from an html page on the `String` variable *"parsedText"*.

But my `TextView` named "data" is inside the for loop and i want to print each line of `String`, line by line in my `TextView`. Please help me with a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the text each time instead of concatenating. It's also very inefficient using `String` like this in a loop.  Instead, use a `StringBuilder`.  Try this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");

for (Element eHead : eHeadder){
    if(eHead.tagName().equals("p"){
       sb.append(eHead.text());
       sb.append("\n");
       Log.d("testing5", ehead.text());
    } 
}

runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){ 
        data.setText(sb.toString());                            }    
     });
}
```

This reduces the number of `String`s created in the loop, reducing memory usage and increasing performance and also only sets the `TextView` text once.  Much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Append `\n` with every parsed `String` your pulling and attach it to `TextView`.

```
 for (Element eHead : eHeadder) 
 {
 String tag = eHead.tagName();
 String addNextLine="";
   if(tag.equals("p")
    {
    final String parsedText = eHead.text();
     Log.d("testing5", parsedText);
     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
     {
      public void run() { 
       addNextLine = parsedText + "\n";
      data.setText(addNextLine);
                        }    
      });
   }
  }
```